# SVG path doesn't render correctly in D3 force network graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have no idea what is happening here, but when I draw my network diagram, it ends up like this :

[image: Path issue D3 force network]

Notice the blue lines to the right. I have a zooming ability, and when I zoom, the blue paths on the right disappear.

My code base is huge, so I'll try get a codePen together of an example to see if I can recreate it. But I used this as a guideline for creating curved links :

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693

This is when I hit the issue.

Some code for the network creation :

Data

```
var bilinks = [];
edges.forEach(function (d) {
    var s = d.source;
    var t = d.target;
    var i = {};
    edges.push({
        source: s,
        target: i
    }, {
        source: i,
        target: t
    });

    nodes.push(i);
    bilinks.push({
        source: s,
        target: t,
        middleNode: i
    });
});
```

Path creation :

```
linkEnter
    .append('path')
    .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return d.id
    })
    .attr('class', 'network-path')
    .attr('stroke', function (d) {    
        return colour(d.color);
    })
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .on('click', function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
```

Perhaps there is a similar question out there, but I'm not sure what to search for.

By the way, thie blue lines on the right are not selectable with the developer selector tool. I'm not sure how it would, but looks similar to when you have a loose monitor connection, I'm really not sure.

Added :

[image]

So, I've hidden the nodes, and gone into the elements area. Hovered over the paths you see above, and as you can see, the boundary is only small. When I hide the content in the blue box, the bunch of paths to the right disappear. When I unhide the elements, they return. I can not select the paths to the right via the select tool in dev tools.

EDIT

Tick functionality, drawing the path :

```
link.selectAll('path').attr('d', function (d) {
    // ----
    // Total difference in x and y from source to target
    var diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    var diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

    // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
    var pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

    // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
    var offsetX = (diffX * nodeSize) / pathLength;
    var offsetY = (diffY * nodeSize) / pathLength;

    // return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + (d.target.x - offsetX) + "," + (d.target.y - offsetY);

    var thisPath = 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y +
        'S' + d.middleNode.x + ',' + d.middleNode.y +
        ' ' + (d.target.x - offsetX) + ',' + (d.target.y - offsetY);

    return thisPath;

});
```

Here is a codePen of the Bostock example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePJbKZ

If you drag one of the nodes ontop of the other, you should be able to see the issue.

Comment: I have a :hover ability on my nodes, when I hover over one of them, some of the extra paths to the right dissapear, but when I unhover, they return.

Comment: Could you add a working example so that others can troubleshoot?

Comment: your link paths have no `d` attribute?

Comment: @rioV8 where would that matter ?

Comment: how do want to see something of the `path`?

Comment: @rioV8 sorry i dont follow ....

Comment: The `d` element is the "directions" that create the path, so if you are having problems with your paths, it is important to show the code that creates them. Please post your code here so that we can help solve your problem.

Comment: ahh sorry my bad, i understand now. This is done in the tick function, I have added it to the question. I presume the 'd' is the direction ?

Comment: You will not get a nice Smooth Bezier when you use `S` after `M`, use a `C`

Comment: where should I use 'c' ? @rioV8

Comment: in the creation of the link path. Like Alien asked: without all the relevant code it keeps a guessing game

Comment: also in the bostock example you see these strange artifacts, drag the orange nodes and look closely, also at the top of the graph

Comment: i have added the code to the question, you mentioned I should be using C instead of the S, I replaced that and it errors. Yeah I saw that too. I'll get a demo up asap

Comment: @rioV8 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePJbKZ if youre interested, thanks

Comment: Look up the docs of `path` `d` elements and you see `C` has different parameters. Why don't you use your JSON file, anonimised if needed, it has the effect more

Comment: @rioV8 changing the 'S' to a 'Q' seemed to solve the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the rendering of the Cubic Bezier splines when the points are co-linear.

If you set the `d3.forceManyBody()` to a strength of `-1` the effect is more visible.

It looks like it is a render problem (rounding error) in the erasing of these Cubic Bezier splines. If you drag a node over the ghost lines they disappear because this part of the SVG is re-rendered.

Choosing a different spline type `Q` or `L` (straight line) does not have this erase problem.