# When adding new data, the curve on the paths increases too much

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have managed to get an example fiddle together which replicates the issue I am currently facing : http://jsfiddle.net/gp0u5rLu/71/

[image: Overly curved paths]

As you can see from the image, the paths are way too curved. You can replicate this by hitting the Add Data button. I'm sure it's to do with how the curved links have been configured.

I followed this example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693

And there you create , what looks like, an intermediary node that is used as a point to curve the path towards.

Here is some of the logic for creating the bilinks dataset :

```js
edges.forEach(function(link) {
  var s = link.source = nodeById.get(link.source),
    t = link.target = nodeById.get(link.target),
    i = {}; // intermediate node
  nodes.push(i);
  edges.push({
    source: s,
    target: i
  }, {
    source: i,
    target: t
  });
  bilinks.push([s, i, t]);
});
```

You can see an empty node gets added to the data set. However, what happens when data gets added when you click on the button, I do not really understand.

I thought perhaps, it was creating the same intermediary nodes, thus pulling the path further away, but I am not too sure how this is exactly working.

I need the curved links, as in my data set, there could be multiple links between two nodes, so I need a way of seeing all of them.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: to prevent artifacts use `Quadratic` (Q) splines not Smooth Bezier Splines (S) https://stackoverflow.com/a/52629919/9938317

Comment: @rioV8 unsure if you noticed, but that was the question i asked not so long ago. The example in this question did not have the Quadratic spline, however, i have made the change and the issue is still there : http://jsfiddle.net/gp0u5rLu/73/ hit the update a few times

Comment: after 1 run the link.source/target are now objects **not** id's

Comment: @rioV8 but they're objects before anything gets rendered. It goes through some logic to point at the node not just the ID and then gets rendered ? Is there an issue here ?